# GCC Windows __asm RDTSC clobber

Tags: c++, c, gcc, assembly, windows-xp

So I'm trying compile some C in GCC for windows. Long story short I can't get Visual Studios to compile an EXE that works on XP. So I thought I'd give GCC a try.

The code it's struggling with is:

```
__asm __volatile ("rdtsc": "=a" (lower), "=d"(upper));
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
HITWxp.c:22:2: error: inconsistent operand constraints in an 'asm'
__asm __volatile ("rdtsc": "=A" (lower), "=D"(upper));
^
```

Now it compiles when I change the line to this:

```
__volatile ("rdtsc": "=A" (lower));
```

I have noticed its converting the "=a" from the first example to the capital "=A" in the second example. So I figured that it's not case sensitive.

The end result needs to be and EXE that works on WinXP/7/8/8.1 x86/x64.

Any ideas?

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: What version of gcc are you using?

Comment: 4.8.1 I did think this. If it's due to that how do I get the new version in Windows? Because GCC does produce an EXE that works in XP

Comment: Or how would I compile it in Linux for Windows. Because I understand by splitting the line that is producing the error produces the RDTSC of both x86 and x64 OS's. So I kinda need that one :)

Comment: what type are you using for lower and upper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine on MingW32 and CygWin:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main ( void )
{
    uint32_t lower = 0, upper = 0;

    asm volatile ("rdtsc": "=a" (lower), "=d" (upper));

    uint64_t ull = ((uint64_t) upper << 32) + lower;
    printf ("%08X %08X\n", upper, lower);
    printf ("%llu\n", ull);
    return 0;
}
```

and Visual Studio 2010:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void )
{
    unsigned _int64 ull = 0;

    _asm
    {
        rdtsc
        mov dword ptr ull, eax
        mov dword ptr ull+4, edx
    }

    printf("%I64u\n",ull);
    return 0;
}
```

and this one should work on both Visual Studios, x86 and x64:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <intrin.h>    

int main ( void )
{
    unsigned _int64 ull = 0;

    ull = __rdtsc();    // "Intrinsics"

    printf("%I64u\n",ull);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I had the variables "lower" & "upper" as unsigned long long. That's the only difference between your solution and mine? What the hell? Thank you. But now I'm worried that my results are going to be different?

Comment: I edited the code but I can't check it on Win64

Comment: It works find. I'm getting the correct results :) Thanks

Comment: The last snippet should use `#include <intrin.h>` on Visual Studio

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Done. Sorry. I wonder why my compiler didn't complain.